# ImportError:No module named 'pdfminer3k' despite conda list shows 'pdfminer3k' already installed

Tags: python, import

Hello and thanks in advance from a newbie. I have recently started dabbling in python and have the need to use the module pdfminer3k.

I am using Anaconda (Python 3.5), and have seemingly got the module pdfminer3k already installed. To verify this, in terminal when I type

```
conda list
```

I can clearly see in there

```
pdfminer3k                1.3.1                     <pip>
```

However when I try to use it (import pdfminer3k), I get the error:

```
'ImportError: No module named 'pdfminer3k''
```

I've looked online for the past two days and haven't been able to come up with an answer. I tried to install it using the following

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/auto pdfminer3k
```

However this shows that it is only available for platform linux-64 (I'm using OSX) so doesn't seem to work.

So given the fact that it is already installed (as verified with the conda list), what could be the cause for this error. Any help you can offer would be much appreciated. I've been banging my head against the wall in frustration.

Comment: If you are using OS X, please consider getting a correct Python environment installed in the first place http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/ and then follow instructions on setting up a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess that is one route. However, I quite like Anaconda overall so it would be a shame to have to shift to vanilla Python rather than finding a solution (unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion).

Comment: Found the answer! It seems while pdfminer3k is indeed installed, it is still referred to as pdfminer.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems for some reason doing a

```
conda list
```

Only shows pdfminer3k as installed. Looking inside the site-packages folder one can see two folders that reference to pdfminer namely pdfminer, as well as pdfminer3k-1.3.1-py3.5.egg-info

When you look inside the second folder (with the egg), you can see in the installed file that the installation location is pdfminer. So long story short, the module can be called by using

```
import pdfminer
```